# How to perform "cleanup" operations when a SharePoint 2013 visual studio workflow is cancelled/terminated?

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I'm creating a SharePoint 2013 visual studio workflow (not a .NET 3.5 workflow). At the beginning of the workflow I assign permissions to the list item the workflow is attached to (by making use of a custom WCF service), and once the workflow has completed, I reset the permissions to a previous state.

The problem I have is that when the workflow gets cancelled/terminated (by the user) before the end of the workflow is reached, the list item permissions need to get set back to a previous state, but because the workflow is cancelled/terminated before the end of the workflow is reached, I can't change the permissions.

Is there a way for me to react to the workflow being cancelled/terminated, which will allow me to set the list item permissions back to its previous state?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add even reciever from one of the fallowing:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and get back to you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work. The event receiver gets attached, but the code never gets executed.
I think its because SharePoint 2013 Workflows run as a separate web service.

Comment: @Appelman i think it is becouse of "termination" is not count as completed

Comment: I don't think so. To test both our theories, I created 'on workflow starting' and 'on workflow started' event receivers. I placed breakpoints in each of the methods, and neither of them got hit on execution